# App crashed with dyld`__abort_with_payload when using scollviewproxy and @available in iOS 13 SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios13

I am developing a new UI for my app and I am going from UIKit to SwiftUI. I want to be able to use a scrollViewProxy to manage my automatic scrolling when for example my view expands beyond the borders of the screen, and from what I've read I should use a scrollviewproxy? (any other ideas? Don't want to wrap this in UIKit!!) I must support iOS 13 in my app, BUT I have chosen to ignore this small UX design feature for those using iOS 13 so it is ok that automatic scrolling isn't supported for iOS 13 users.

This is what crashes my app with error code ***dyld`__abort_with_payload***
and also this ***symbol stub for: type metadata accessor for SwiftUI.ScrollViewProxy***

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
@State var scrollProxy: ScrollViewProxy?
```

Any ideas on what I could do? Don't want to wrap this and use UIKit!

**--UPDATE--**

Instead of having a scrollViewProxy as a property, you can save the scroll function and use that where ever you need to programatically scroll.

Like this

```
@State var scroll: ((_ id: String, _ anchor: UnitPoint?) -> Void)? = nil
```

And then

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    mainBody.onAppear {
        scroll = proxy.scrollTo
    }
}
```

And use like this

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *), let scroll = scroll {
    withAnimation {
        scroll("callLinkButton", .bottom)
            proxy.scrollTo(, anchor: )
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because `@State` is a source of truth and`ScrollViewProxy` is a `struct` so the value of the `@State var scrollProxy: ScrollViewProxy?` is not the same that you would get from `ScrollViewReader{ scrollProxy in` it is just a copy that would not affect the `ScrollViewReader`. That is probably why you are getting an accessor crash. UIKit is probably your best bet or creating your own `ScrollView` with gestures and such.

Comment: But why does this work on iOS 14 ->, but not 13? Thought @available would make the compiler totally ignore that line?

Comment: Probably a bug, there have been many changes to SwiftUI and a lot of workarounds that worked in iOS 13 stopped working in iOS 14, 15 and even with 16. IOS 13 was barely over a Beta when it comes to capabilities, and bugs.